# How to create communication between two android apps using service

Tags: android

I'm having two apps A and B what i want to do is how to send message (communicate) between two apps A and B using service. I went threw some tutorials but it it not contains communication in either way.
Tutorials or leads are helpful to me
Thx in adv.

Comment: Services aren't designed to facilitate communication between two apps. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think a `Service` is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Broadcast Receiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)